# CakePHP session sharing between two apps, on the same domain

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am having two CakePHP application working on the same domain.

They are located at `localhost:8080/wishlist` and `localhost:8080/lighthouse`.

"Wishlist" and "lighthouse" are each separate CakePHP applications.

The login page is at `localhost:8080/lighthouse`, and I want the session generated by the lighthouse application to be used in the wishlist application.

The directory structure is

```
/htdocs
    /wishlist
        /app
        /config
        ....
    /lighthouse
        /app
        /config
        ....
```

I have edited the `core.php` file for each application. I am using the same session cookie name and the same security sale but I am not able to get the session on the wishlist application.

How can I share a session in between my two applications?

Comment: As a side note, your directory structure could be `/htdocs/wishlist/config`, `/htdocs/lighthouse/config`, `/htdocs/cake`, `/htdocs/vendors`. By convention, this would allow both applications to share the same cake installation and global vendors directory without any manual configuration, and it would respond to the same URLs. A common mistake is thinking that the `app` directories cannot be renamed, which isn't the case. :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, install [Firefox](http://www.getfirefox.com), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and [Firecookie](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firecookie/). This will add a 'Cookies' tab to Firebug making it simple to inspect your cookies.

Cookies consist of multiple parts: name, value, domain, path, expires, etc. You are most interested in the 'path' part of the cookie here I believe.

By default CakePHP will restrict the path of each cookie to the subdirectory of your app. For example, when you visit `/wishlist`, a cookie will be created but it will be restricted to the `/wishlist` subdirectory. When you then go to `/lighthouse` the previous cookie won't apply, so thinking that you have no cookie/session, a new one is created that is restricted to the `/lighthouse` subdirectory.

You need to change the path of created cookies to `/` so they persist across all subdirectories. This should be as easy as adding `ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/');` to both application's `app/config/bootstrap.php` files.

Comment: Thanks a lot the solution worked for me.
I have posted the details here http://www.amityadav.name/cakephp-sharing-sessions-between-apps-on-the-same-domain/

Answer (score 0):

You should look at developing each one as a plugin or developing them in the same app. I am not sure why you would want to develop two seperate apps when they are sharing a login screen.

Comment: Its the result of a bad programming that the earlier programmer did. These were two separate apps and now they want them to merge.