# Managing session between two cakephp app engine

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, session-variables

I am working on a project using CakePHP version 1.3, with two app folders, one for English and another one for Spanish.

In some cases, my application depends on session data from English to Spanish and vice versa.  How can I get session data from each of these applications in the other one?

Comment: Neil, Kiran has already done it in energy project. Please talk to him for it. If you are satisfy with him then talk to me.

Comment: Why do different languages need to be different folders?  CakePHP has [Internationalization and Localization support](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Internationalization-Localization.html) built in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP session sharing between two apps, on the same domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996274/cakephp-session-sharing-between-two-apps-on-the-same-domain)

Answer (score 1):

if you're applications are on the same server you can simply create a session variable and access it
$_SESSION['globalVariables']

or you can store your data in redis or some sort of cache.